# How to record screens navigation in android?

Tags: android, record, screens

I am developing an application which captures screenshots and records the screens as video, without rooting the device.

I tried the ASL Demo which is given in the following link

http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/

It's working only to take screenshots. How can I record the screens in android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, If we do any work or perform any activity, the total activity need to be record and store it in sdcard.

Comment: Hi, Please help me. I am waiting for good result.

Comment: ok you are screen shot any screen like i.e, home,menu and other screens!

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to take screenshot without run native method?

Comment: it's not possible for non-rooted devices and you can screen shot in your application frame by frame after join the frames convert to video!

Comment: ok. But asl library is working in non-rooted device. Here need to run native "run.bat" file through command prompt. Thereafter possible to take screenshot of anyscreens and all the screens can be stored in sdcard. Now i need to record that screens while taking screenshot and play it as video.

Comment: video recording not possible non-rooted device. screen capture possible for you application like talking tom cat app to video screen recording!